# Install sphinx compilated doc from setup.py

Tags: python, python-sphinx, setuptools, restructuredtext, setup.py

I want to install some HTML on-line doc that is made (understand compiled from rSt) using [sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) along with the python code into the site-package. I want to to this using **setup.py**.

To be more specific, I want to complile my `*.rst` files to HTML and then copy then into site-package from the setup.py file when the user types `python setup.py install`.

Does someone know how to do this ? I look into sphinx and setuptools doc but was not able to find the info.

The reason I want to do it, is that my package is a GUI tool and the HTML is the on-line help of it. It is displayed into GUI's internal browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted you'll need a `MANIFEST.in` file to include the docs directory:

```
recursive-include docs *
```

Now in your `setup.py` you could programmatically generate the sphinx documentation from your `*.rst` files.

Here's an example on how to do that automatically when `python setup.py install` is run:

```
from distutils.core import setup

# set dependencies, we need sphinx to build doc
dependencies = ['sphinx']

setup(
    name='my_package'
    # rest of your setup
)

# auto-generate documentation
import sphinx

# automatically build html documentation
# For example:
#   format = 'html'
#   sphinx-src-dir = './doc'
#   sphinx-build-dir = './doc/build'
sphinx.build_main(['setup.py', '-b', '<format>', '<sphinx-src-dir>', '<sphinx-build-dir>'])
```

Like this you can run `sphinx-build` as needed ([Documentation](http://sphinx-doc.org/tutorial.html)).

**Note:** It might be a good idea to add a [Custom command](http://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-to-add-custom-build-steps-and-commands-to-setup-py.html) to your `setup.py` for separating documentation generation (f.e. `python setup.py make_doc [params]`) and install routine (`python setup.py install`). This way the user could easily supply parameters `format`, `sphinx-src-dir` and `sphinx-build-dir`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them into your MANIFEST.in and then build the package

```
recursive-include docs *
```

Then it will be distributed with your egg

Comment: What if I want the doc to be compiled on the user side (when he run the setup) ?